# Hacer descuento si se cumple la condición

Tags: netbeans, java-swing

Soy nuevo en esto. Estoy haciendo una aplicación para un almacen, con dos ventanas.
La primera pedira valor unitario y numero de articulos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el proceso cuando de click al boton "continuar" pasará a la segunda ventana y se multiplican los dos valores ingresados (v/u y N/a).

Luego de esto pasa a la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando el usuario de click al boton "Calcular" si el valor total es mayor a $50000 realice un descuento del 20% y lo ingrese en el textfield de Descuento 1

Pero ahi el problema, no realiza el proceso o la condicion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AYUDA, POR FAVOR. Ya he intentado de varias maneras y no he podido e intente a traves de tutoriales pero no logro dar con el resultado.

Aqui adjunto el proyecto por mediafire, no sé si por aquí stackoverflow se puede adjuntar

http://www.mediafire.com/file/kteem2ajs6eg461/Almacen.zip/file

Comment: Hola @Angel te recomiendo que cuando compartas codigo , adjuntes el codigo y  no una foto ya que asi no podremos probarlo. De que tipo es la variable convertidor?

Comment: @Capt.Teach Listo, adjunto pagina por mediafire del proyecto: http://www.mediafire.com/file/kteem2ajs6eg461/Almacen.zip/file
No sé si por aquí stackoverflow se puede subir el proyecto.

Convertidor es una variable tipo Double.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: no he ejecutado el proyecto, pero viendo la foto del codigo que has pasado a mi si que me funciona(me sale 27000.0). Tal vez te falte actualizar  `TX_D1` en la pantalla con algun evento